# Sending a variable to the Mapper Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to get an input from the user and pass it to my mapper class that I have created but whenever the value always initialises to zero instead of using the actual value the user input.

How can make sure that whenever I get the variable it always maintain the same value. I have noticed that job1.setMapperClass(Parallel_for.class); creates an instance of the class hence forcing the variable to reinitialize to its original value. Below is the link to the two classes. I am trying to get the value of times from RunnerTool class.

[Link to Java TestFor class](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwSPoDdRDme8NzVmYWRlODctNmEzNC00ZjcwLWEzZDEtZTJiODVmNDI0NWZk&hl=en_US%20https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwSPoDdRDme8NDE1Yzc4N2MtYTM0Yy00M2MxLWIzOWMtMmE1YjhlNmU4NmM3&hl=en_US)

[Link to RunnerTool class](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwSPoDdRDme8NDE1Yzc4N2MtYTM0Yy00M2MxLWIzOWMtMmE1YjhlNmU4NmM3&sort=name&layout=list&num=50)

// setup method in the Mapper

```
@Override
public void setup(Context context) {
    int defaultValue = 1;
    times = context.getConfiguration().getInt("parallel_for_iteration", defaultValue );
    LOG.info(context.getConfiguration().get("parallel_for_iteration") + " Actually name from the commandline");
    LOG.info(times + " Actually number of iteration from the commandline");
}
```

// RunnerTools class

conf.setInt(ITERATION, times);

Answer (score 1):

You should note that mapper class will be recreated on many cluster nodes so any initalization done to the instance of the mapper class when running the job will not affect other nodes. Technically relevant jar file/s will be distributed among nodes and then mappers will be created there.
So as pointed in the answer above, the only way to pass information to the mappers is using Configuration class.

Comment: I tried using the configuration but I was getting null for the property and it returns the default value. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: // RunnerTools class
final static String ITERATION = "parallel_for_iteration";
conf.setInt(ITERATION, times);

Answer (score 0):

`Mapper` get's initialized by reflection, so you can not let the user interact with the mapper class.

Instead you have your `Configuration` object, which you have to provide if you're setting up your job. There you can set this using `conf.set("YOUR KEY", "YOUR VALUE")`. In your `Mapper` class you can override a method called `setup(Context context)`, there you can get the value using `context.getConfiguration().get("YOUR KEY")`. And maybe save to your mapper local variable.

Comment: I tried using the configuration but I was getting null for the property and it returns the default value. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your code, you never put the key into the configuration, how should this work?

Comment: I used conf.setInt(ITERATION, times); iteration is defined as protected final static String ITERATION = 
     "parallel_for_iteration";

Comment: Sorry, but in the code you've linked on Docs is no such call.

Comment: The above question has been updated with the changes. Look at the question again you will noticed that I have added some codes that are not on the original links.

Comment: When I print the get() on the runnertool class it prints the assigned value but from the Parallel_for class it prints null.. Any idea why?